# GWT - text area - getText() - how to save some formatting?

Tags: java, gwt2

I am just wondering... Is there an optimal way to keep "new line" formatting in TextArea? I mean when for example:

UI something like:

```
 ------------
|Hello world | line A (\\n)
|Hello world | line B (\\n)
|...         | line i (\\n)
 ------------

String t=ta.getText();
```

... so t is missing all ta "new line(s)" ; As a result t value is

> Hello worldHello world...

So my question is...

How to keep "new line" format for getText() method? Or maybe there some more optimal way?

*I am not pretty sure is the GWT's TextArea supports `\\n` lines separator. But is there a way to catch new line on fly I mean on user presses 'Enter' button? If I get text on 'Enter' was pressed no formatting is been kept. The only thing I get is a straight string but I want somehow keep line separation marks or something to restore text as it was originally in TextArea component*

Thanks

Comment: What is the delimiter you are using to detect the end of line ?

Answer (score 1):

If the text entered in teh textarea end with \n, then you can use

```
     String[] lines = yourTextArea.getText().split("\\n");// split according to new line
     for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++)
              {
                System.out.println("lines are"+lines[i].toString());// display using toString()
              }
```

Is this what you are looking for??. This works if your are using java swing.

Comment: I am looking a way to save line wrapping... getText() method returns a String which doesn't contain any \\n or something. For example if I set text from textarea A to textarea B then textarea B losses textarea A text wrapping; so sharing text or something like that is a quite problematic thing :(

Comment: Did you try RichTextArea without a toolbar instead of TextArea?

Comment: @Raghunandan I mean GWT. I guess is there a way to keep line wrap in String field for example?

Comment: @Andrei Volgin, I know what RichTextArea is but I am interested in TextArea and getting text with \\n or something like <br> or etc where the original line was wrapped.

Comment: I am not pretty sure is the GWT's TextArea supports \\n lines separator but I'll try. But is there a way to catch new line on fly I mean on user presses 'Enter' button? If I get text on 'Enter' was pressed no formatting is been kept. The only thing I get is a straight string but I want somehow keep line separation marks or something to restore text as it was in TextArea component :( Actually that is the question...